# Como puedo hacer una consulta SQL que solo me aparezca un registro en un datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo mi formulario cuadrillas en donde vas agregando personal, pero cuando se muestran en el datagridview, no quiero que me muestren todos si no que solo un registro por folio.

A continuación muestro un ejemplo de esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: distinct? group by? todo depende de tu consulta.. agrega la consulta que estas haciendo

Comment: Si solo queres que te muestre uno tenes que usar SELECT TOP 1. Si no queres que te muestre repetidos tenes que usar SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 3):

Pues agruparlo por el numero de folio de la siguiente manera:

```
GROUP BY Folio, Nombre_de_la_cuadrilla
```

Que es lo que hace esto, pues agrupa a todos los folios con el mismo nombre de la cuadrilla.

Vale decir

Si tu consulta fuera la siguiente:

```
SELECT FOLIO, NOMBRE_CUADRILLA
FROM MYTABLA;
```

Mostraria como ejemplo algo asi:

```
____________________________________________________
|    FOLIO   |         NOMBRE_CUADRILLA            |
___________________________________________________
| MOC. 00001 | 3 albañiles + 3guardias de seguridad|
| MOC. 00001 | 3 albañiles + 3guardias de seguridad|
| MOC. 00001 | 3 albañiles + 3guardias de seguridad|
| MOC. 00002 | 2 mecanico + 2 ayudantes general    |
| MOC. 00002 | 2 mecanico + 2 ayudantes general    |
| MOC. 00002 | 2 mecanico + 2 ayudantes general    |
___________________________________________________
```

Si colocas `GROUP BY` de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT FOLIO, NOMBRE_CUADRILLA
FROM MYTABLA
GROUP BY FOLIO, NOMBRE_CUADRILLA;
```

El resultado seria:

```
____________________________________________________
|    FOLIO   |         NOMBRE_CUADRILLA            |
___________________________________________________
| MOC. 00001 | 3 albañiles + 3guardias de seguridad|
| MOC. 00002 | 2 mecanico + 2 ayudantes general    |
___________________________________________________
```

Espero que puedas solucionar tu caso. Exito!

Comment: y que va a traer en nombre de la cuadrilla?? max??

Comment: Depende de lo que hayas seleccionado en tu consulta. Si colocas `SELECT FOLIO, NOMBRE_CUADRILLA FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY FOLIO, NOMBRE_CUADRILLA`, esto hará que te traiga todos los folios agrupados, con el nombre agrupado tambien. Vale decir si 3 veces te aparece MOC. 00001, 3 albañiles + 3guardias de seguridad. Entonces el group by hara que la consulta en vez de 3 veces el mismo dato, solo te muestre uno

Comment: aclaraselo a OP en la respuesta...

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi, soy algo nuevo en este foro

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda ya me salio la consulta en SQL, pero ahora no se como aplicarla en un datagridview en c# con linq

Solo realizo una lista de la siguiente manera, pero mi duda es como aplicarla con group by:

private void setConfCuadrilla()
        {                      
                DataContext temp = new DCGeneralDataContext();
                List<confCuadrilla> administracion = temp.GetTable<confCuadrilla>().ToList();
                this.dgvResultadoCuadrilla.DataSource = administracion;                
            }           
        }

Answer (score 0):

a tu consulta agregale lo siguiente

```
GROUP BY Folio
```

esto deberia solucionar tu problema

Comment: y que va a traer en nombre de la cuadrilla?? max??

Comment: @gbianchi el nombre de la cuadrilla es el mismo en cada folio, no habra problema con eso